# Clean method in order to update collection in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i'm sorry if this question has already been asked, but i'm in trouble with my method of updating collection in Entity Framework.

Let me explain the situation : 
 - I have for example one model CUSTOMER with some properties and a collection of ORDERS (for example).
 - Let's imagine we have an admin page on wich we can edit all the ORDERS for a customer, and when we submit the form, it will send us back the object CUSTOMERS with updated ORDERS (some added, some updated and some deleted).

For the moment i use something like this in order to compare old collection and new collection and determine which object i need to delete/update/add

```
 var toRemove = new List<ORDERS>();
        var toAdd = new List<ORDERS>();
        foreach (
            var order in
                oldList.Where(
                    order =>
                    newList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.link_id == order.link_id) == null))
        {
            toRemove.Add(order);
        }
        foreach (
            var order in
                newList.Where(
                    order =>
                    oldList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.link_id == order.link_id) == null))
        {
            toAdd.Add(order);
        }
        foreach (var ORDERSe in toRemove)
        {
            bdd.ORDERS.Remove(ORDERSe);
        }
        foreach (var ORDERSe in toAdd)
        {
            ORDERSe.pjt_id = project_id;
            bdd.ORDERS.Add(ORDERSe);
        }

        foreach (
            var order in
                newList.Where(
                    order =>
                    oldList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.link_id == order.link_id) != null))
        {
            var child = oldList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.link_id == order.link_id);
            bdd.Entry(child).CurrentValues.SetValues(order);
        }
```

But i'm unconfortable with this, because in my mind, entity framework should be able to do the work for me !

I was hoping something like :

```
customer.orders = newOrders;
```

Did i missed anything about entity framework or ? 
Because when i do this, it just duplicate my orders.
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: I really think you should start from scratch. You need to consolidate all those forEach loops..

Comment: Why don't you use [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method?

Comment: Is this an effort to use your own `Orders` POCO class?  You are trying to map your class to that of your EF class?  Why not just use the EF class?  [Self Tracking Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff407090(v=vs.100).aspx), though depricated, [or other EF API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613668) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: The point is not really the quality of code (just wrote it as an example ! ) but the way we update collection (3 loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly make it cleaner using .Except() and .Intersect(), but the concept doesn't really change, AFAIK you still have to individually remove, update & add the entries in loops...

```
var oldList = new List<ORDERS>();
var newList= new List<ORDERS>();

var IdsToRemove = oldList.Select(t => t.link_id).Except(newList.Select(t => t.link_id));
var IdsToAdd = newList.Select(t => t.link_id).Except(oldList.Select(t => t.link_id));
var IdsToUpdate =  newList.Select(t => t.link_id).Intersect(oldList.Select(t => t.link_id));

//remove
bdd.orders.where(x => IdsToRemove.Contains(x.link_id)).ForEach(x => bdd.Remove(x));
//add
foreach(var order in newList.Where(x -> IdsToAdd.Contains(x.link_id))
{
   bdd.Orders.Attach(order);
   bdd.Entries(order).EntityState = EntityState.Added;
}
//update
foreach(var order in newList.Where(x -> IdsToUpdate .Contains(x.link_id))
{
   bdd.Orders.Attach(order);
   bdd.Entries(order).EntityState = EntityState.Modified;
}

bdd.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i'm unconfortable with this, because in my mind, entity framework
>   should be able to do the work for me !

In fact, EF does the Work for you. Using the data context SaveChanges method EF should be able to save all your changes at once:

```
DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

For your convinience you can still override this method. Internally you should use something like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
   var changeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>();

   if (changeSet != null)
   {
      foreach (var entry in changeSet.Where(c => c.State != EntityState.Unchanged))
      {
          entry.Entity.ModifiedDate = DateProvider.GetCurrentDate();
          entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = UserName;
      }
   }
   return base.SaveChanges();
```

}